# Error while passing values to another controller function

Tags: grails, groovy

My controller function is as follows:

```
  def saveData(String name,String message) { 
     println "HI WORLD"
     println "NAME IS "+ name
     println "NAME IS "+ message
  }
```

From another controller function I'm passing values to the above controller function:

```
def submitMessage() {
    def mes =new Message()
    mes.saveData("HI","JJ")    
}
```

I end up having the following error, how can I resolve it?

```
Message: No signature of method: myPro.Message.saveData() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [HI, JJ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subject suggests that you are invoking a method on a controller but your code and error message indicate that you are invoking a method on an instance of `myPro.Message`, which is not a controller.  You should verify that there is a `saveData` method in your `myPro.Message` class that accepts 2 `String` arguments.

Comment: btw… you should never invoke a controller action method directly.  The code in your description isn’t doing that, but the question title suggests that you might have had that in mind.

Comment: How else can i save records in the DB. My model contains `name` and `message` only.

Comment: "How else can i save records in the DB.".  I don't understand the question. Invoking controller action methods directly isn't necessary to interact with your database.  You can make the database calls in the first controller action, or have the action invoke a service method which does the DB work. There is never a good reason for a controller action method to directly invoke another controller action method.